# Pygame scrolling background lag

Tags: python, background, python-3.x, pygame, lag

In pygame I wish to have a scrolling background so that the player can move around a large area, I have done this rather easily, but the game runs very slowly.

some of my code: http://pastebin.com/1EzDV7mc

what am I doing inefficiently?
how can I make it run faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [A Newbie Guide to PyGame](http://pygame.org/docs/tut/newbieguide.html)

In particular:

1. Use surface.convert()
2. Ideally use dirty rect animation, only updating the parts of the screen that have changed, not the entire view. That said I have previously used whole screen updates with PyGame (which is what you need to do for a game where the whole screen is constantly scrolling), and it's not that bad on a modern computer as long as you don't have too many objects.

Not mentioned in that guide:

1. you are aiming for 60fps with clock.tick(60), aim lower, 30fps is fine and won't hose the CPU as much
2. If you need to do full screen updates for scrolling, then either a) don't use many objects or b) stop using PyGame and switch to OpenGL
3. why are you blitting images using their mid points, rather than their top left point? A mistake?
4. It is more usual to store size attributes as seperate width and height attribute, not as a list you have to index. This makes your code much clearer.

Comment: And also : screen.fill((0, 0, 0)) ? Why, because you blit all the world. So fill the screen seem a heavy operation for do nothing. Or i miss something in the code.

Comment: if the whole screen is scrolling and the background is mostly blank (e.g. when testing, or say a spaceship moving through black space) then you may need to fill the whole screen each frame

Comment: ok, suppose some part of the screen is blanck, but the code here not shows objects/lot of part of background, but juste one image. So, if it's not covert all the screen (which is mostly improbable) he know what to fill (and not all the screen). And like you previously said : "only updating the parts of the screen that have changed". When you (fill(0,0,0)), there is a conception problem IMO

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what junichiro said, I did find a website giving the information he said plus some.

https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/newbieguide.html

I'm not calling you a newbie, even I learned quite a bit from this website, and I've been using pygame for 6 years.

Also, surface.convert() only works with non-transparent images.  Use surface.convert_alpha(), which works with everything.  I usually create a function so I don't have to type the entire thing every time I want to load an image.  Feel free to use the following 2 lines of code:

```
def loadify(imgname):
    return pygame.image.load(imgname).convert_alpha()
```

This increased the fps of my game from 18 to 30 fps.

Good luck!